# Increasing the value of a variable on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says, every time a certain key is pressed the value of a variable should go up.

I have tried several times to figure this out, but I cant seem to develop a solution to this problem.

Moreover, I'm wondering if it is possible to increase the value of the variable when a key is held down.

**GOAL:** To increase the value of a variable when a **particular** key is pressed and to constantly increase the value when the key is held down.

**PROBLEM:** I am unable to achieve this.

Also, I prefer if your solution is in Jquery, but if this is not possible plain javascript is welcome.

Moreover, if you know of any online article that can help me out, please provide an url to the article.

Also, thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: Do you mean increment by autorepeat (which will usually trigger once, pause, then trigger repeatedly, like in a text editor)? Or increment smoothly (such as you'd find in a game)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      //Press enterkey to see result
      counter++;
      console.log(counter)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hard to keep a button pressed when alert is popping up. But solves it for my first case (autorepeat).

Comment: @Amadan just wanted to show a demo. That is all. That is why I showed an alert. :)

Comment: it would be better to replace alert with console.log(); to check the values

Comment: @AmarShukla I have made the change as per your suggestion. :)

Comment: Thank you this will work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In pure JS

```
  <script>
        var count = 0;
        document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.key === "Enter") {
                count++;
            }
        });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See simple enter counter, simply hit enter to see result of how match you've entered:

```js
(function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('enter-counter'); 
  var counter = parseInt(elem.innerHTML);

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e,v){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
    document.getElementById('enter-counter').innerHTML = ++counter;
    }
  }, false);

})();
```

```html
<div>Enter Counter::: </div><div id='enter-counter'>1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLNoob, there are some great answers here but to be honest I feel like this is something you should have been able to figure out on your own. I am pretty new to JQuery, and one of the greatest things about JQuery adding event listeners for specific types of input. When the event listener catches that input, it can then call a function. This is going to be super helpful for you in the future. Here is a snippet

```js
 $('#button').click(adder);

        function adder(){
          var counter = 0;
          counter++
          console.log(counter)

          }
```

Here is some great documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Here is the documentation for JQuery. 
https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

It includes a lot of awesome stuff!